# How properly set up internal imports in Python package?

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, python-module, python-packaging

I am developing a Python 3 package (say "**Project1**"), which I want to use in another Python project (say "**Project2**"). The structure of the **Project1** is, briefly, like this:

```
/global_project_folder
|-different_garbage...
|-setup.py
|-/src
  |-/project1
    |-__init.py__
    |-mainmodule.py
    |-auxmodule1.py
    |-auxmodule2.py
    |-etc...
```

setup.py contains information about project, like described in [this manual](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/). In this file project mentioned as "project1"

mainmodule.py contains code like this:

```
import auxmodule1
from auxmodule2 import AuxMethod21,AuxMethod22

def MainMethod():
    return auxmodule1.AuxMethod11()*(AuxMethod21()+AuxMethod22())
```

I installed package Project1 as for development, via command:
`python3 -m pip install -e .`
pipdeptree -l reports project1 in list of available packages.

Now, in **Project2**, I want to write a code like this:

```
from project1.mainmodule import MainMethod
```

But when I trying to test **Project2**, it crashes with error "*ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'auxmodule1'*"

If I change **Project1** mainmodule.py like this:

```
import project1.auxmodule1
from project1.auxmodule2 import AuxMethod21,AuxMethod22
```

everything starts working.

But I don't want to modify Project1 like this, because in that case it's code could not work outside of it, and this option is viable.

How can I fix this situation?

I want to keep somehow structure and code of **Project1** untouched - adding to every inner import of the project mention that we are importing module from this project itself looks very unelegant. Is there a way to walkaround?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Comment: Every module has one and only one qualified package location. The module is either a top-level module named `auxmodule1` or a package submodule `project1.auxmodule1`. It can't be both. Where you're importing the module from is completely irrelevant.

Comment: OK. Then I need to explain. Code in `auxmodule1`, `auxmodule2`, etc. has it's own value. I.e., `auxmodule1` could be run standalone, outside of `project1` without modification. But also I need to combine it into something (maybe *not* a package?) what should work as unity for outside projects. How can I do this?

Comment: Is `project1`/`auxmodule1` externally available, or does it only exist as part of the "global project"? If it is externally available or can be packaged separately, then you can look declaring it as a dependency of your current project. Otherwise, you can add everything under `project1` as additional top-level packages/modules inside `setup.py`.

Comment: As a side note, `setup.py` is outdated. You might want to look into switching to setuptools' current `pyproject.toml` interface, or migrating to a different modern build system,

Comment: Well... Some of `auxmodule` really should be available externally I think. You mentioned that I can add all of this as an additional top-level packages, that's sounds as an option. How can I do this?

Comment: OK. I added them as top-level modules through command `py_modules=["mainmodule","auxmodule1"],` in file **setup.py**. It works. Thank you for idea, **Brian61354270**!